# Why are there too many demand rfo offcore responses /offcore requests?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-cache, rfo

`Whiskey Lake i7-8565U`/`Ubuntu 18.04`/`HT enabled`

Consider the following code that writes some garbage data that happened to be in registers `ymm0` and `ymm1` into *16 MiB* statically allocated WB memory in a loop consisting of 6400 iteration (so page fault impact is negligible):

```
;rdx = 16MiB >> 3
xor rcx, rcx
store_loop:
vmovdqa [rdi + rcx*8], ymm0
vmovdqa [rdi + rcx*8 + 0x20], ymm1
add rcx, 0x08
cmp rdx, rcx
ja store_loop
```

Using `taskset -c 3 ./bin` I'm measuring RFO requests by this example and here is the results:

```
Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 3 ./bin':

     1 695 029 000      L1-dcache-load-misses     # 2325,60% of all L1-dcache hits    (24,93%)
        72 885 527      L1-dcache-loads                                               (24,99%)
     3 411 237 144      L1-dcache-stores                                              (25,05%)
       946 374 671      l2_rqsts.all_rfo                                              (25,11%)
       451 047 123      l2_rqsts.rfo_hit                                              (25,15%)
       495 868 337      l2_rqsts.rfo_miss                                             (25,15%)
     2 367 931 179      l2_rqsts.all_pf                                               (25,14%)
       568 168 558      l2_rqsts.pf_hit                                               (25,08%)
     1 785 300 075      l2_rqsts.pf_miss                                              (25,02%)
     1 217 663 928      offcore_requests.demand_rfo                                     (24,96%)
     1 963 262 031      offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response                                     (24,91%)
           108 536      dTLB-load-misses          #    0,20% of all dTLB cache hits   (24,91%)
        55 540 014      dTLB-loads                                                    (24,91%)
        26 310 618      dTLB-store-misses                                             (24,91%)
     3 412 849 640      dTLB-stores                                                   (24,91%)
    27 265 942 916      cycles                                                        (24,91%)

       6,681218065 seconds time elapsed

       6,584426000 seconds user
       0,096006000 seconds sys
```

---

The description of `l2_rqsts.all_rfo` is

> Counts the total number of RFO (read for ownership) requests to L2
>   cache. L2 RFO requests include both L1D demand RFO misses as well as
>   L1D RFO prefetches.

suggesting that DCU can do some sort of RFO prefetches. It was not clear from the desctiption of DCU from `Intel Optimization Manual/2.6.2.4`:

> Data cache unit (DCU) prefetcher — This prefetcher, also known as the
>   streaming prefetcher, is triggered by an ascending access to very
>   recently loaded data. The processor assumes that this access is part
>   of a streaming algorithm and automatically fetches the next line.

So I guess that DCU follows the "access type": If it is RFO then DCU does RFO prefetch.

All of those RFO prefetches should go to L2 along with demand RFO and only some of them (`l2_rqsts.rfo_miss`) should go to the uncore. The `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` counts only demand rfo, but `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` accounts all rfo (demand + dcu prefectch) meaning that the inequality `offcore_requests.demand_rfo < l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` should be held.

**QUESTION 1:** Why is `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` much less then `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` (even `l2_rqsts.all_rfo` less then `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`)

I expected that demand `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` can be matched up with `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` so there should be approximately equal numbers for those Core PMU events

**QUESTION 2:** Why is `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` almost 1.5 times more then `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`?

I'm guessing that L2-streamer also does some RFO prefetches, but it should not be accounted in `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` anyway.

---

**UPD**:

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 3 0x1A4
1
```

L2-Streamer off

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 3 ./bin':

     1 672 633 985      L1-dcache-load-misses     # 2272,75% of all L1-dcache hits    (24,96%)
        73 595 056      L1-dcache-loads                                               (25,00%)
     3 409 928 481      L1-dcache-stores                                              (25,00%)
     1 593 190 436      l2_rqsts.all_rfo                                              (25,04%)
        16 582 758      l2_rqsts.rfo_hit                                              (25,07%)
     1 579 107 608      l2_rqsts.rfo_miss                                             (25,07%)
       124 294 129      l2_rqsts.all_pf                                               (25,07%)
        22 674 837      l2_rqsts.pf_hit                                               (25,07%)
       102 019 160      l2_rqsts.pf_miss                                              (25,07%)
     1 661 232 864      offcore_requests.demand_rfo                                     (25,02%)
     3 287 688 173      offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response                                     (24,98%)
           139 247      dTLB-load-misses          #    0,25% of all dTLB cache hits   (24,94%)
        56 823 458      dTLB-loads                                                    (24,90%)
        26 343 286      dTLB-store-misses                                             (24,90%)
     3 384 264 241      dTLB-stores                                                   (24,94%)
    37 782 766 410      cycles                                                        (24,94%)

       9,320791474 seconds time elapsed

       9,213383000 seconds user
       0,099928000 seconds sys
```

As can be seen `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` got closer to `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss`, but still there is some difference. In the Intel docs of `OFFCORE_REQUESTS_OUTSTANDING.DEMAND_DATA_RD` I found the following:

> Note: A prefetch promoted to Demand is counted from the promotion
>   point.

So my guess is that L2-prefetches were promoted to Demand and counted in the Demand offcore requests. But it does not explain the difference between `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` and `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` which is almost twice now:

`offcore_requests.demand_rfo 1 661 232 864`

vs

`offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response 3 287 688 173`

---

**UPD:**

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 3 0x1A4
3
```

All L2 prefetchers off

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 3 ./bin':

     1 686 560 752      L1-dcache-load-misses     # 2138,14% of all L1-dcache hits    (23,44%)
        78 879 830      L1-dcache-loads                                               (23,48%)
     3 409 552 015      L1-dcache-stores                                              (23,53%)
     1 670 187 931      l2_rqsts.all_rfo                                              (23,56%)
            15 674      l2_rqsts.rfo_hit                                              (23,59%)
     1 676 538 346      l2_rqsts.rfo_miss                                             (23,58%)
           156 206      l2_rqsts.all_pf                                               (23,59%)
            14 436      l2_rqsts.pf_hit                                               (23,59%)
           173 163      l2_rqsts.pf_miss                                              (23,59%)
     1 671 606 174      offcore_requests.demand_rfo                                     (23,59%)
     3 301 546 970      offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response                                     (23,59%)
           140 335      dTLB-load-misses          #    0,21% of all dTLB cache hits   (23,57%)
        68 010 546      dTLB-loads                                                    (23,53%)
        26 329 766      dTLB-store-misses                                             (23,49%)
     3 429 416 286      dTLB-stores                                                   (23,45%)
    39 462 328 435      cycles                                                        (23,42%)

       9,699770319 seconds time elapsed

       9,596304000 seconds user
       0,099961000 seconds sys
```

Now the total number of prefetch requests to l2 (from all prefetchers) is `156 206 l2_rqsts.all_pf`.

---

**UPD:**

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 3 0x1A4
7
```

̶A̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶r̶e̶f̶e̶t̶c̶h̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶t̶u̶r̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶.̶ Only IP prefetcher enabled

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 3 ./bin':

     1 672 643 256      L1-dcache-load-misses     # 1893,36% of all L1-dcache hits    (24,92%)
        88 342 382      L1-dcache-loads                                               (24,96%)
     3 411 575 868      L1-dcache-stores                                              (25,00%)
     1 672 628 218      l2_rqsts.all_rfo                                              (25,04%)
            10 585      l2_rqsts.rfo_hit                                              (25,04%)
     1 684 510 576      l2_rqsts.rfo_miss                                             (25,04%)
            10 042      l2_rqsts.all_pf                                               (25,04%)
             4 368      l2_rqsts.pf_hit                                               (25,05%)
             9 135      l2_rqsts.pf_miss                                              (25,05%)
     1 684 136 160      offcore_requests.demand_rfo                                     (25,05%)
     3 316 673 543      offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response                                     (25,05%)
           133 322      dTLB-load-misses          #    0,21% of all dTLB cache hits   (25,03%)
        64 283 883      dTLB-loads                                                    (24,99%)
        26 195 527      dTLB-store-misses                                             (24,95%)
     3 392 779 428      dTLB-stores                                                   (24,91%)
    39 627 346 050      cycles                                                        (24,88%)

       9,710779347 seconds time elapsed

       9,610209000 seconds user
       0,099981000 seconds sys
```

---

**UPD:**

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 3 0x1A4
f
```

All prefetchers disabled

```
 Performance counter stats for 'taskset -c 3 ./bin':

     1 695 710 457      L1-dcache-load-misses     # 2052,21% of all L1-dcache hits    (23,47%)
        82 628 503      L1-dcache-loads                                               (23,47%)
     3 429 579 614      L1-dcache-stores                                              (23,47%)
     1 682 110 906      l2_rqsts.all_rfo                                              (23,51%)
            12 315      l2_rqsts.rfo_hit                                              (23,55%)
     1 672 591 830      l2_rqsts.rfo_miss                                             (23,55%)
                 0      l2_rqsts.all_pf                                               (23,55%)
                 0      l2_rqsts.pf_hit                                               (23,55%)
                12      l2_rqsts.pf_miss                                              (23,55%)
     1 662 163 396      offcore_requests.demand_rfo                                     (23,55%)
     3 282 743 626      offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response                                     (23,55%)
           126 739      dTLB-load-misses          #    0,21% of all dTLB cache hits   (23,55%)
        59 790 090      dTLB-loads                                                    (23,55%)
        26 373 257      dTLB-store-misses                                             (23,55%)
     3 426 860 516      dTLB-stores                                                   (23,55%)
    38 282 401 051      cycles                                                        (23,51%)

       9,377335173 seconds time elapsed

       9,281050000 seconds user
       0,096010000 seconds sys
```

Even though prefetchers are disabled `perf` reports `12` as `pf_miss` (reproducible across different runs with different values). This is probably counting error. Also `1 672 591 830 l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` has slightly larger value then `1 662 163 396 offcore_requests.demand_rfo` which I also tend to interpret as counting error.

---

**Hypothesis:** DCU RFO Prefetch missing L2 and going off core are accounted in `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`.

The hypothesis works if L2-streamer switched off: `102 019 160 l2_rqsts.pf_miss + 1 579 107 608 l2_rqsts.rfo_miss = 1 681 126 768`; `1 661 232 864 offcore_requests.demand_rfo`

The hypothesis also works if all the prefetchers turned off: `1 684 510 576 l2_rqsts.rfo_miss`; `1 684 136 160 offcore_requests`.

In case of all PF turned off `L1-dcache-load-misses` is approximately equal to `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` which in turns equals to `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`

The thing I still have no idea about is why  `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` has much larger value then `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`

Comment: How many demand RFOs should there be? I cannot tell from the code shown because I don't know what's in `rdx` and how many different physical pages are being accessed. How many of them are you expecting to miss in the L1? Are you only counting user-mode events? Are using `perf`? If yes, then do these counts  include any other significant pieces of code. Is HT disabled? You can remove `offcore_requests_outstanding.demand_rfo` and `l2_rqsts.all_demand_data_rd` to avoid multiplexing with HT disabled. Repeat the experiment multiple times and show the standard deviation for each event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that the loop is writing to 2^18 cache lines and there is an outer loop (not shown in the question) that executes the inner loop (which is the one shown) 6400 times. So the expected total number of demand RFOs is 2^18*6400 = 1,677,721,600 and the expected number of retired store instructions is 1677721600*2 = 3,355,443,200. The measured number of stores `L1-dcache-stores` is about 3.410 billion, which is about 55 million more than what is expected. This event count should be accurate, so I presume that there is other code not shown in the question that is affecting the event counts. The load event counts also indicate that there are many loads coming from somewhere, which have a significant impact on the counts of the events `l2_rqsts.all_pf`, `l2_rqsts.pf_hit`, `l2_rqsts.pf_miss`. I've already asked whether there are any other significant pieces of code included in the measurements in my comment.

From the results of the first experiment with all prefetchers enabled, it appears that `l2_rqsts.rfo_hit` + `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` add up to an amount that is nearly equal to the expected number of demand RFOs. The L2 streamer can actually prefetch RFOs as documented in the Intel optimization manual, which explains how there can be `l2_rqsts.rfo_hit`. I don't know why `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss` is not equal to `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`. I think the event `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` is accurate. Try to disable only the L1D prefetchers and keep the L2 prefetchers enabled and see whether execution time increases. If the L1D prefetchers actually send any significant number of RFOs, there should be enough write hits in the L1D such that it makes a difference in performance.

The results of the second experiment with the L2 streamer disabled are very close to what is expected. `l2_rqsts.rfo_hit` is very small and `l2_rqsts.all_rfo` is nearly equal to `offcore_requests.demand_rfo`, which is equal to the expected number of demand RFOs. This provides an experimental evidence that the L1D prefetchers don't prefetch RFOs. `l2_rqsts.all_pf` should be zero in this case since both L2 prefetchers are disabled.

In the last experiment, you've only turned off three of the four data cache prefetchers; you missed the DCU IP prefetcher. The count of `2_rqsts.all_rfo` in this case is even closer to what is excepted. Try to disable the DCU IP prefetcher as well and see whether `l2_rqsts.rfo_hit` (and maybe `l2_rqsts.all_pf`) become zero.

[Erratum 058](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/8th-gen-core-spec-update.pdf) in the spec update document of your processor says that `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` may overcount and that `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` can be used instead. This explains why `offcore_response.demand_rfo.any_response` is larger than what is expected in all of the experiments and it also suggests that `offcore_requests.demand_rfo` is reliable.

Comment: _The L2 streamer can actually prefetch RFOs as documented in the Intel optimization manual_ I suppose you meant the following text from `3.7.3`: _DPL can also be triggered by read for ownership (RFO) operations. The L2 Streamer can also be triggered by DPL requests for L2 cache misses._ Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @St.Antario I was referring to Section 2.5.5.4 which says about the L2 streamer that *Monitored read requests include L1 DCache requests initiated by load and store operations...* Although this Section is under Sandy Bridge (Section 2.5), this particular statement applies to later microarchitectures as well. Actually, most of Section 2.5 applies to later microarchitectures. I've not experimented on an Ice Lake processor yet, but I've not seen indications that any of the data prefetchers have significantly changed/improved other than becoming a little more aggressive.

Answer (score 4):

For **Question 1**, the answer (on Skylake at least, but very likely to be the same for Whisky lake) is that the L2 RFO events don't count when they are initiated by a prefetch: not when the prefetch is triggered and not even when the RFO later hits or misses in the L2. You can count these events by setting the prefetch bit on your event (set 0x10 in the umask) and in this case you'll see double counts as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122072/149138).

The events you see are a somewhat random subset of RFOs where the L2 prefetcher didn't help. The offcore counters apparently don't have such a problem: even if a request is initiated by a prefetch, it can be promoted to a demand request when a demand hits the request in progress.

You can find additional details [here](https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench/wiki/perf-stat-recipies#l2_rqsts), and you should double check exactly what events your version of perf uses as Intel changed the event definitions as described in that last link.

Comment: I assume you meant `0x24` event number. For my WhL `DisplayFamily_DisplayModel`: `06_8e` the only specified event was `0x21`. So it is generally undocumented to use `0x20` and `0x01` separately. Probably I missed something, but the event masks `0x01` and `0x20` were explicitly documented for `SnB` (`Table 19-15/ Intel Manual Vol. 3`) and `IvB` (`Table 19-17/ Intel Manual Vol. 3`), but not for `Haswell` or later.

Comment: Unfortunately umask `0x10` counts zero events on my cpu.

Comment: Could you please clarify which `DisplayFamily_DisplayModel` you ran your tests on?

Comment: @Antario - you need to combine the umask `0x10` with other bits to get a meaningful result. Of course this is all "undocumented", that's the point of the stuff in the second link which explains how the event is actually working.

Comment: This was on SKL, maybe 6_5E, I'll check later.

Comment: Yeah it was 6_5E. I expect Whiskey Lake to be nearly identical in PMU functionality regardless of the documentation.