# AVX512 auto-vectorized C++ matrix-vector functions are much slower when source = destination, in-place

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, avx512, auto-vectorization

I've tried to write a few functions to carry out matrix-vector multiplication using a single matrix together with an array of source vectors. I've once written those functions in C++ and once in x86 AVX512 Assembly to compare the performance with the Intel VTune Profiler. When utilizing the source vector array as the destination array the Assembly variants perform 3.5x to 10x faster than the C++ counterpart, but when utilizing different source and destination arrays the Assembly variants barely perform better than the C++ counterpart achieving almost the same performance... sometimes even minimally worse.

Another thing which I can't understand is, why the C++ counterparts can even get near the same or better performance level than the Assembly variants when using different source and destination arrays even though the Assembly code is much shorter and also according to the static analysis tools uica and llvm-mca multiple times faster. [uica.uops.info](https://uica.uops.info/)

I wouldn't want to make this post too long as it already will be, so I'm posting only the code for the functions to carry out mat4-vec4 multiplication.

This is the code for the Assembly variant, which assumes the matrix to be transposed:

```
alignas(64) uint32_t mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_vpermps_index[64]{    0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 12,
                                                            1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 13,
                                                            2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14, 14,
                                                            3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 15 };

void __declspec(naked, align(64)) mat4_mul_vec4_avx512(vec4f_t* destination, const mat4f_t& src1, const vec4f_t* src2, uint32_t vector_count) {
__asm {
    vbroadcastf32x4 zmm16, xmmword ptr[rdx]
    vbroadcastf32x4 zmm17, xmmword ptr[rdx + 16]

    vbroadcastf32x4 zmm18, xmmword ptr[rdx + 32]
    vbroadcastf32x4 zmm19, xmmword ptr[rdx + 48]

    vmovups zmm20, zmmword ptr[mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_vpermps_index]
    vmovups zmm21, zmmword ptr[mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_vpermps_index + 64]

    vmovups zmm22, zmmword ptr[mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_vpermps_index + 128]
    vmovups zmm23, zmmword ptr[mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_vpermps_index + 192]

    vmovups zmm24, zmmword ptr[r8]

    vpermps zmm25, zmm20, zmm24
    vpermps zmm26, zmm21, zmm24
    vpermps zmm27, zmm22, zmm24
    vpermps zmm28, zmm23, zmm24

    xor eax, eax

    align 32
    mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_loop:

        vmovups zmm24, zmmword ptr[r8+rax+64]

        vmulps zmm29, zmm16, zmm25
        vpermps zmm25, zmm20, zmm24

        vfmadd231ps zmm29, zmm17, zmm26
        vpermps zmm26, zmm21, zmm24

        vfmadd231ps zmm29, zmm18, zmm27
        vpermps zmm27, zmm22, zmm24

        vfmadd231ps zmm29, zmm19, zmm28
        vpermps zmm28, zmm23, zmm24

        vmovups zmmword ptr[rcx+rax], zmm29

    add rax, 64

    sub r9, 4
    jnz mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_loop

    ret
    }
}
```

This is the C++ variant, which assumes the matrix to not be transposed:

```
void mat4_mul_vec4_cpp(vec4f_t* destination, const mat4f_t& src1, const vec4f_t* src2, uint32_t vector_count) {
for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < vector_count; ++i0) {
    destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
    destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
    destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
    destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
    }
}
```

Which resulted in the following Assembly code by the Intel C++ Compiler:

```
00007FF69F123D50  sub         rsp,38h  
00007FF69F123D54  vmovaps     xmmword ptr [rsp+20h],xmm8  
00007FF69F123D5A  vmovaps     xmmword ptr [rsp+10h],xmm7  
00007FF69F123D60  vmovaps     xmmword ptr [rsp],xmm6  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123D65  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rdx]  
00007FF69F123D69  vmovss      xmm1,dword ptr [rdx+4]  
00007FF69F123D6E  vmovss      xmm2,dword ptr [rdx+8]  
00007FF69F123D73  vmovss      xmm3,dword ptr [rdx+0Ch]  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123D78  vmovss      xmm4,dword ptr [rdx+10h]  
00007FF69F123D7D  vmovss      xmm5,dword ptr [rdx+14h]  
00007FF69F123D82  vmovss      xmm16,dword ptr [rdx+18h]  
00007FF69F123D89  vmovss      xmm17,dword ptr [rdx+1Ch]  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123D90  vmovss      xmm18,dword ptr [rdx+20h]  
00007FF69F123D97  vmovss      xmm19,dword ptr [rdx+24h]  
00007FF69F123D9E  vmovss      xmm20,dword ptr [rdx+28h]  
00007FF69F123DA5  vmovss      xmm21,dword ptr [rdx+2Ch]  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123DAC  vmovss      xmm22,dword ptr [rdx+30h]  
00007FF69F123DB3  vmovss      xmm23,dword ptr [rdx+34h]  
00007FF69F123DBA  vmovss      xmm24,dword ptr [rdx+38h]  
00007FF69F123DC1  vmovss      xmm25,dword ptr [rdx+3Ch]  
    for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < vector_count; ++i0) {
00007FF69F123DC8  lea         rax,[r8+3A9800h]  
00007FF69F123DCF  cmp         rax,rcx  
00007FF69F123DD2  jbe         mat4_mul_vec4_cpp+150h (07FF69F123EA0h)  
00007FF69F123DD8  lea         rax,[rcx+3A9800h]  
00007FF69F123DDF  cmp         rax,r8  
00007FF69F123DE2  jbe         mat4_mul_vec4_cpp+150h (07FF69F123EA0h)  
00007FF69F123DE8  mov         eax,0Ch  
00007FF69F123DED  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123DF0  vmulss      xmm26,xmm0,dword ptr [r8+rax-0Ch]  
00007FF69F123DF8  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm1,dword ptr [r8+rax-8]  
00007FF69F123E00  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm2,dword ptr [r8+rax-4]  
00007FF69F123E08  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm3,dword ptr [r8+rax]  
00007FF69F123E0F  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+rax-0Ch],xmm26  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123E17  vmulss      xmm26,xmm4,dword ptr [r8+rax-0Ch]  
00007FF69F123E1F  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm5,dword ptr [r8+rax-8]  
00007FF69F123E27  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm16,dword ptr [r8+rax-4]  
00007FF69F123E2F  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm17,dword ptr [r8+rax]  
00007FF69F123E36  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+rax-8],xmm26  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123E3E  vmulss      xmm26,xmm18,dword ptr [r8+rax-0Ch]  
00007FF69F123E46  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm19,dword ptr [r8+rax-8]  
00007FF69F123E4E  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm20,dword ptr [r8+rax-4]  
00007FF69F123E56  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm21,dword ptr [r8+rax]  
00007FF69F123E5D  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+rax-4],xmm26  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123E65  vmulss      xmm26,xmm22,dword ptr [r8+rax-0Ch]  
00007FF69F123E6D  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm23,dword ptr [r8+rax-8]  
00007FF69F123E75  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm24,dword ptr [r8+rax-4]  
00007FF69F123E7D  vfmadd231ss xmm26,xmm25,dword ptr [r8+rax]  
00007FF69F123E84  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+rax],xmm26  
    for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < vector_count; ++i0) {
00007FF69F123E8B  add         rax,10h  
00007FF69F123E8F  cmp         rax,3A980Ch  
00007FF69F123E95  jne         mat4_mul_vec4_cpp+0A0h (07FF69F123DF0h)  
00007FF69F123E9B  jmp         mat4_mul_vec4_cpp+2FEh (07FF69F12404Eh)  
00007FF69F123EA0  vbroadcastss ymm0,xmm0  
00007FF69F123EA5  vbroadcastss ymm1,xmm1  
00007FF69F123EAA  vbroadcastss ymm2,xmm2  
00007FF69F123EAF  vbroadcastss ymm3,xmm3  
00007FF69F123EB4  vbroadcastss ymm4,xmm4  
00007FF69F123EB9  vbroadcastss ymm5,xmm5  
00007FF69F123EBE  vbroadcastss ymm16,xmm16  
00007FF69F123EC4  vbroadcastss ymm17,xmm17  
00007FF69F123ECA  vbroadcastss ymm18,xmm18  
00007FF69F123ED0  vbroadcastss ymm19,xmm19  
00007FF69F123ED6  vbroadcastss ymm20,xmm20  
00007FF69F123EDC  vbroadcastss ymm21,xmm21  
00007FF69F123EE2  vbroadcastss ymm22,xmm22  
00007FF69F123EE8  vbroadcastss ymm23,xmm23  
00007FF69F123EEE  vbroadcastss ymm24,xmm24  
00007FF69F123EF4  vbroadcastss ymm25,xmm25  
00007FF69F123EFA  xor         eax,eax  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123EFC  vmovups     xmm26,xmmword ptr [r8+rax]  
00007FF69F123F03  vmovups     xmm27,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+10h]  
00007FF69F123F0B  vmovups     xmm28,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+20h]  
00007FF69F123F13  vmovups     xmm29,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+30h]  
00007FF69F123F1B  vinsertf32x4 ymm26,ymm26,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+40h],1  
00007FF69F123F24  vinsertf32x4 ymm27,ymm27,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+50h],1  
00007FF69F123F2D  vinsertf32x4 ymm28,ymm28,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+60h],1  
00007FF69F123F36  vinsertf32x4 ymm29,ymm29,xmmword ptr [r8+rax+70h],1  
00007FF69F123F3F  vshufps     ymm30,ymm26,ymm27,14h  
00007FF69F123F46  vshufps     ymm31,ymm29,ymm28,41h  
00007FF69F123F4D  vshufps     ymm6,ymm30,ymm31,6Ch  
00007FF69F123F54  vmulps      ymm7,ymm6,ymm0  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F58  vmulps      ymm8,ymm6,ymm4  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F5C  vshufps     ymm30,ymm30,ymm31,39h  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F63  vmulps      ymm31,ymm6,ymm18  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F69  vmulps      ymm6,ymm6,ymm22  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F6F  vfmadd231ps ymm7,ymm30,ymm1  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F75  vfmadd231ps ymm8,ymm30,ymm5  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F7B  vfmadd231ps ymm31,ymm30,ymm19  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F81  vfmadd231ps ymm6,ymm23,ymm30  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123F87  vshufps     ymm26,ymm26,ymm27,0BEh  
00007FF69F123F8E  vshufps     ymm27,ymm29,ymm28,0EBh  
00007FF69F123F95  vshufps     ymm28,ymm26,ymm27,6Ch  
00007FF69F123F9C  vfmadd231ps ymm7,ymm28,ymm2  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FA2  vfmadd231ps ymm8,ymm28,ymm16  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FA8  vfmadd231ps ymm31,ymm28,ymm20  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FAE  vfmadd231ps ymm6,ymm24,ymm28  
        destination[i0].element_[0] = src1.element_[0][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[0][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[0][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[0][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FB4  vshufps     ymm26,ymm26,ymm27,39h  
00007FF69F123FBB  vfmadd231ps ymm7,ymm26,ymm3  
        destination[i0].element_[1] = src1.element_[1][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[1][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[1][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[1][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FC1  vfmadd231ps ymm8,ymm26,ymm17  
        destination[i0].element_[2] = src1.element_[2][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[2][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + src1.element_[2][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[2][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FC7  vfmadd231ps ymm31,ymm26,ymm21  
        destination[i0].element_[3] = src1.element_[3][0] * src2[i0].element_[0] + src1.element_[3][1] * src2[i0].element_[1] + +src1.element_[3][2] * src2[i0].element_[2] + src1.element_[3][3] * src2[i0].element_[3];
00007FF69F123FCD  vfmadd231ps ymm6,ymm25,ymm26  
00007FF69F123FD3  vpunpckldq  ymm26,ymm7,ymm8  
00007FF69F123FD9  vpunpckldq  ymm27,ymm31,ymm6  
00007FF69F123FDF  vpunpckhdq  ymm28,ymm7,ymm8  
00007FF69F123FE5  vpunpckhdq  ymm29,ymm31,ymm6  
00007FF69F123FEB  vpunpcklqdq ymm30,ymm26,ymm27  
00007FF69F123FF1  vpunpckhqdq ymm26,ymm26,ymm27  
00007FF69F123FF7  vpunpcklqdq ymm27,ymm28,ymm29  
00007FF69F123FFD  vpunpckhqdq ymm28,ymm28,ymm29  
00007FF69F124003  vinsertf32x4 ymm29,ymm30,xmm26,1  
00007FF69F12400A  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rcx+rax],ymm29  
00007FF69F124011  vinsertf32x4 ymm29,ymm27,xmm28,1  
00007FF69F124018  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rcx+rax+20h],ymm29  
00007FF69F124020  vshuff64x2  ymm26,ymm30,ymm26,3  
00007FF69F124027  vmovupd     ymmword ptr [rcx+rax+40h],ymm26  
00007FF69F12402F  vshuff64x2  ymm26,ymm27,ymm28,3  
00007FF69F124036  vmovupd     ymmword ptr [rcx+rax+60h],ymm26  
    for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < vector_count; ++i0) {
00007FF69F12403E  sub         rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF80h  
00007FF69F124042  cmp         rax,3A9800h  
00007FF69F124048  jne         mat4_mul_vec4_cpp+1ACh (07FF69F123EFCh)  
    }
}
00007FF69F12404E  vmovaps     xmm6,xmmword ptr [rsp]  
00007FF69F124053  vmovaps     xmm7,xmmword ptr [rsp+10h]  
00007FF69F124059  vmovaps     xmm8,xmmword ptr [rsp+20h]  
00007FF69F12405F  add         rsp,38h  
00007FF69F124063  vzeroupper  
00007FF69F124066  ret
```

This is the calling code for the benchmark, when using the same source and destination vector array:

```
int main() {
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    SetThreadPriorityBoost(GetCurrentThread(), false);
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    mat4f_t matrix{ {0, 1, 2, 3,
                    4, 5, 6, 7,
                    8, 9, 10, 11,
                    12, 13, 14, 15} };

    vec4f_t* dst_vector = new vec4f_t[1'000'000]{};
    vec4f_t* src_vector = new vec4f_t[1'000'000]{};

    vec3f_t* dst_vector0 = new vec3f_t[1'000'000]{};
    vec3f_t* src_vector0 = new vec3f_t[1'000'000]{};

    for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < 1000000; ++i0) {
        src_vector[i0] = vec4f_t{ (float)i0, (float)i0, (float)i0, (float)i0 };
        src_vector0[i0] = vec3f_t{ (float)i0, (float)i0, (float)i0 };
    }

    set_mxcsr0(0b1111'1111'1100'0000);

    for (uint64_t i0{}; i0 < 30000; ++i0) {
        for (uint32_t i1{}; i1 < 16; ++i1) {
            reinterpret_cast<float*>(matrix.element_)[i1] = 1. / i0;
        }
        mat4_mul_vec4_avx512(src_vector, matrix, src_vector, 240000);
        mat4_mul_vec4_cpp(src_vector, matrix, src_vector, 240000);
        mat4_mul_vec3_avx512(src_vector0, matrix, src_vector0, 240000);
        mat4_mul_vec3_cpp(src_vector0, matrix, src_vector0, 240000);
        fps();
    }

    for (uint32_t i0{}; i0 < 1000000; ++i0) {
        std::cout << src_vector0[i0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << src_vector[i0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When testing with different source and destination arrays src_vector/src_vector0 as the first parameter would be replaced by dst_vector/dst_vector0.

These are the benchmark results when using the same source and destination arrays:

[Same source/destination arrays, Assembly performs much better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDOxg.png)

These are the benchmark results when using different source and destination arrays:

[Different source/destination arrays, Assembly performs nearly the same as C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54n5m.png)

The benchmarks have been created on a machine with Windows 11 with an 11th Gen i7-11850H Tiger Lake CPU using the Intel C++ Compiler 2024 and, as already mentioned, the Intel VTune Profiler.

There are a few things which I don't understand:

1. Why does the speed vary when using different/the same source and destination arrays?
   Does it have anything to do with the cache in this case?
2. Why does the C++ counterpart even reach such good performance near the Assembly variant when using different source and destination arrays?

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Each iteration of your asm `mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_loop` does one vector-matrix product?  And it's the same matrix but different vectors every time? It looks like ICX unrolled by two, but it is doing an unreasonable amount of shuffling.  Is your loop software-pipelining the shuffles?  It looks like each `vpermps` produces an output that isn't read until the next iteration.  But the last iteration loads + shuffles a vector that never gets used, since there's no multiply + store before `ret`.  Are you reading past the end of the input?

Comment: Yeah, uiCA predicts 1 iteration (2 vectors) per 14.14 cycles for the C++ loop on Tiger Lake (or 1 input vector per 7.07 cycles), vs. one per 4.02 cycles from your asm, saturating ports 0 and 5 (FMA and shuffles).  And only needing 1 load + store per 2 clocks, which gives it some room for extra cache accesses for misaligned data.  The C++ version is 54 front-end uops, mostly bottlenecked on port 1 (imperfect scheduling making shuffles and FMAs compete sometimes.)

Comment: Correction, those ratios are right but it's 1 iteration per 8 `float4` 16-byte vectors for C++, 1 iter per 4 `float4` vectors for asm.

Comment: Did you turn on the compilers optimizer or is this unoptimized results?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The code is optimized in favor of speed and allowing the compiler to use all available instruction sets of the CPU.

Comment: @Loran That may be. But I was specifically talking about whether compiler optimizations were enabled - like `-O2` or `-O3` for `gcc` or `clang` and possibly even whether LTO (Link Time Optimization (aka `-flto`)) was enabled. Those compiler options can make a big difference sometimes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl There is no -flto specified but -O2 is. I don't think the compiler is optimizing away the function call or the work it is doing since the benchmark code enforces it by outputting the results and disassembly also shows that. I've experimented with different input sizes by passing a lower amount of vectors to be processed. This resulted in the assembly function performing much better (1.5x to 2x) than the C++ variant as Peter Cordes already calculated. This seems to be more of a memory issue, which can be seen confirmed by the old and new benchmark results.

Comment: This means the cache utilization has to be optimized. What I could think of, especcially when the dest and source array are not the same, would be to use alternating iteration direction for the processing loop?? Meaning the function would be called once to process the elements in forward direction and when calling the function again to then process them backswards? And repeatedly switching the direction to increase the probability that the function will find the items of the last function call in cache.

Comment: The vectors are meant to be used as vertex data in a software renderer. For every frame these are taken and transformed accordingly. And those are expected to be in the original object space before being transformed, as defined in the model file. So utilizing the same source and destination vector array wouldn't be very practical for this, because it would overwrite the object space vertex data. A way to use the same dst and source array would be to take the inverse of the previous transformation matrix for the previous frame and multiply it with the transformation matrix of the current frame.

Comment: This would result in the vertex data being transformed in object space and then in the current world space. It would computationally be as efficient because only one matrix would be used but it would probably cause the float values to deviate more and more from the ones in the model file because of them being continuously altered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first VTune screenshot (the source=dest version) shows the **cpp version running 100% scalar ops (far right column)**, vs. the separate dest case running 100% packed SIMD FP ops.

It's common for auto-vectorization to check for overlap and fall back to a scalar loop if an output overlaps any input, not making a third version that's specialized for dst=src (e.g. perhaps loading everything first, if that still matches the C++ semantics for that case).  **So it's probably using the scalar fallback because its checks detected overlap.**  (In code that always has disjoint dst and src, you'd use `__restrict` to promise that and optimize away those checks.  It might happen to compile to asm that works in the perfect overlap dst=src case, but that's still UB so don't do it, it could break in future or with different surrounding code to inline into.)

If your source special-cases the dst=src case, that could get auto-vectorized.

---

> also according to the static analysis tools uica and llvm-mca multiple times faster. uica.uops.info

It's not that extreme;  uiCA predicts a 1.75x speedup for your asm vs. LLVM's on Tiger Lake.

- [uiCA for the C++ auto-vectorized inner loop](https://uica.uops.info/?code=%25define%20ptr%20%0D%0A%25define%20xmmword%0D%0A%25define%20ymmword%0D%0Atop%3A%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20xmm26%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%5D%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20xmm27%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B10h%5D%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20xmm28%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B20h%5D%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20xmm29%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B30h%5D%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm26%2Cymm26%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B40h%5D%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm27%2Cymm27%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B50h%5D%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm28%2Cymm28%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B60h%5D%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm29%2Cymm29%2Cxmmword%20ptr%20%5Br8%2Brax%2B70h%5D%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm30%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%2C14h%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm31%2Cymm29%2Cymm28%2C41h%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm6%2Cymm30%2Cymm31%2C6Ch%20%20%0D%0A%20vmulps%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm7%2Cymm6%2Cymm0%20%20%0D%0A%20vmulps%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm8%2Cymm6%2Cymm4%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm30%2Cymm30%2Cymm31%2C39h%20%20%0D%0A%3B%0D%0A%20vmulps%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm31%2Cymm6%2Cymm18%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vmulps%20%20%20%20%20%20ymm6%2Cymm6%2Cymm22%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm7%2Cymm30%2Cymm1%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm8%2Cymm30%2Cymm5%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm31%2Cymm30%2Cymm19%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm6%2Cymm23%2Cymm30%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm26%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%2C0BEh%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm27%2Cymm29%2Cymm28%2C0EBh%20%20%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm28%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%2C6Ch%20%20%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm7%2Cymm28%2Cymm2%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm8%2Cymm28%2Cymm16%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm31%2Cymm28%2Cymm20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm6%2Cymm24%2Cymm28%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20vshufps%20%20%20%20%20ymm26%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%2C39h%20%20%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm7%2Cymm26%2Cymm3%20%20%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm8%2Cymm26%2Cymm17%20%20%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm31%2Cymm26%2Cymm21%20%20%0D%0A%20vfmadd231ps%20ymm6%2Cymm25%2Cymm26%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckldq%20%20ymm26%2Cymm7%2Cymm8%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckldq%20%20ymm27%2Cymm31%2Cymm6%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckhdq%20%20ymm28%2Cymm7%2Cymm8%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckhdq%20%20ymm29%2Cymm31%2Cymm6%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpcklqdq%20ymm30%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckhqdq%20ymm26%2Cymm26%2Cymm27%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpcklqdq%20ymm27%2Cymm28%2Cymm29%20%20%0D%0A%20vpunpckhqdq%20ymm28%2Cymm28%2Cymm29%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm29%2Cymm30%2Cxmm26%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brcx%2Brax%5D%2Cymm29%20%20%0D%0A%20vinsertf32x4%20ymm29%2Cymm27%2Cxmm28%2C1%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovups%20%20%20%20%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brcx%2Brax%2B20h%5D%2Cymm29%20%20%0D%0A%20vshuff64x2%20%20ymm26%2Cymm30%2Cymm26%2C3%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovupd%20%20%20%20%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brcx%2Brax%2B40h%5D%2Cymm26%20%20%0D%0A%20vshuff64x2%20%20ymm26%2Cymm27%2Cymm28%2C3%20%20%0D%0A%20vmovupd%20%20%20%20%20ymmword%20ptr%20%5Brcx%2Brax%2B60h%5D%2Cymm26%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20sub%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF80h%20%20%0D%0A%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C3A9800h%20%20%0D%0A%20jne%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20top%20%20%20%3B%20mat4_mul_vec4_cpp%2B1ACh%20%2007FF69F123EFCh%0D%0A&syntax=NASM&uArchs=TGL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0) - predicts 14.14 cycles per iteration (128 bytes of data = 8x `float4`) using YMM vectors.  With perfect scheduling, a back-end port throughput bottleneck of 13.33 cycles, but apparently it predicts too many of the shuffles will get scheduled to port 1 and steal cycles from the MULs/FMAs.
  54 front-end uops / iteration = 6.75 per `float4`
- [uiCA for the asm loop](https://uica.uops.info/?code=%20%20%20%20.balign%2032%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_loop%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vmovups%20zmm24%2C%20zmmword%20ptr%5Br8%2Brax%2B64%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vmulps%20zmm29%2C%20zmm16%2C%20zmm25%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpermps%20zmm25%2C%20zmm20%2C%20zmm24%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vfmadd231ps%20zmm29%2C%20zmm17%2C%20zmm26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpermps%20zmm26%2C%20zmm21%2C%20zmm24%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vfmadd231ps%20zmm29%2C%20zmm18%2C%20zmm27%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpermps%20zmm27%2C%20zmm22%2C%20zmm24%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vfmadd231ps%20zmm29%2C%20zmm19%2C%20zmm28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vpermps%20zmm28%2C%20zmm23%2C%20zmm24%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vmovups%20zmmword%20ptr%5Brcx%2Brax%5D%2C%20zmm29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%20rax%2C%2064%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sub%20r9%2C%204%0D%0A%20%20%20%20jnz%20mat4_mul_vec4_avx512_loop&syntax=asIntel&uArchs=SKX&uArchs=TGL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0) - predicts 4.02 cycles per iteration (64 bytes = 4x `float4`).  As expected, if loads/stores aren't a bottleneck, out-of-order exec has no problem overlapping work across iterations and saturating port 0 with FMAs, port 5 with shuffles.  The indexed addressing-mode isn't a problem [since you don't use it as a memory operand for an ALU instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes), just for pure-load / pure-store.
  12 total (fused-domain) uops per iter = 3 per `float4`, so more hyperthreading-friendly if the other logical core has some scalar integer work that can run on ports 1 and 6, or while this thread stalls on load/store bandwidth.

So in the best-case no-stall case, `14.14/2 / 4.02 = 1.756` speed ratio in cycles per `float4`.  Maybe you missed the work per iteration factor (look at the pointer increments and addressing mode offsets), or you copy/pasted the whole function instead of just the inner loop?  uiCA treats the asm as a loop body whether it ends with a branch or not, assuming any earlier branches are not-taken.

**Memory / cache bandwidth bottlenecks might be the limiting factor, leaving both running at about the same speed?**  For equivalent code (not like this with tons of extra shuffles with 256-bit vectors), unaligned data can be maybe 15% worse DRAM bandwidth on Skylake Xeon with 512-bit vectors than with 256-bit vectors (where only every *other* load/store is a cache-line split.)

Source = destination is better for cache footprint since you're only touching half as much data.  And better for memory bandwidth: without NT stores, a write costs a read+write if the data isn't already hot in cache, include a Read For Ownership to get the old value of a cache line and exclusive ownership.  (I'm not sure if there are any optimizations for an aligned store of a whole 64-byte cache line, like whether that can just invalidate other copies without doing an RFO but without bypassing / evicting from cache like NT stores, instead [like how `rep movsb` / `rep stosb` microcode works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy).)  Anyway, if DRAM bandwidth was a bottleneck, you'd expect in-place to be 1.5x as fast vs. copy, modulo other factors like mixed read+write having some overhead for the DRAM itself.

So the in-place case might be unshackling your asm from bandwidth bottlenecks, as well as causing the C++ to face-plant as it runs scalar code, magnifying the difference.

---

It looks like your code uses the same matrix every time, but with different vectors.  And you load 4 `float4` vectors as one ZMM vector.

With software pipelining of the load+shuffle ahead of the MUL+FMAs, which is really not necessary, all CPUs with AVX-512 have pretty deep out-of-order execution buffers to find instruction-level parallelism across iterations.  It's a fairly short dependency chain.

Also, you load + shuffle a final vector but don't FMA + store it.  You could peel a final set of MUL/FMA + store out of the end of the last iteration, and have your loop counter do one fewer iteration.

For Zen 4, you might use `cmp/jne` on the pointer instead of `sub`/`jnz` on a separate counter.  Zen can macro-fuse `cmp/jcc` but not `sub/jcc`.

---

It looks like ICX unrolled to do 128 bytes of data per iteration, but it is doing a *lot* of shuffle uops per input vector.  One `vpermps` (or `vpermt2ps` if it needs to pull data from 2x YMM instead of 1x ZMM with the default `-mprefer-vector-width=256`) per multiply should be better, but it's not inventing shuffle constants other than immediates for `vshufps`.

It looks like it broadcasted each scalar element of the matrix to a separate YMM register, with 16x `vbroadcastss` instructions.  So this requires shuffles to line up the results.

---

Even with "client" chips having 1/clock ZMM FMA/mul/add but 2/clock YMM, I'd have expected your asm to be faster due to both front-end and back-end execution-port throughput bottlenecks from all those shuffles.  Even if your data isn't aligned by 64, so every load and store is a cache-line split.  (512-bit vectors make aligned data more important than with 256-bit.)  Even with possible clock-speed penalties from using 512-bit vectors.

You probably didn't *need* to write this in asm.  You could probably get about the same asm with intrinsics like `_mm512_loadu_ps` and `_mm512_fmadd_ps`.  `asm{}` does let you `align 32` for that one specific loop to help out the uop cache, but Tiger Lake has a working LSD (loop buffer).  (Skylake-X only has its uop cache, no LSD, and it has the JCC erratum creating even more code-alignment potholes for the bottom of loops.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

I didn't know that overlapping memory blocks could prevent vectorization to take place... thanks for the info. 

The loop in the asm function processes 4 vectors per iteration to make use of the entire 512 bit registers. The vpermps instructions are used to reorder the data of the vectors for the next iteration. 

I've noticed pretty late that the loop reads further from the input as it should because my attention was mostly caught by the performance of the functions. I don't think it's a big deal since 4 dummy vectors can be passed to solve that.

Comment: In this case both arrays contain much more vectors than what is actually processed. I've also tried to further optimize the asm function by unrolling the loop to fill the gaps between the mul and fma instructions. Since the mul and fma instruction both have a latency of 4 clock cycles, I took the above code and unrolled it to 4x times to process 16 vectors per iteration, but there was no improvement in performance. The performance was very very minimally worse because in the unrolled version there also was overhead for saving non-volatile registers.

Comment: @Loran: Oh, right, that makes sense, 4 floats are 16 bytes.  And ICX / LLVM's loop is processing 128 bytes = 8 vectors per iteration, twice as much data per iteration as your asm; I was looking at the addressing modes and pointer increments to see how much data was accessed each iteration.

Comment: You don't really need software-pipelining: all CPUs with AVX-512 (except Xeon Phi) have deep out-of-order execution buffers to see across loop iterations and hide instruction latency.  You have plenty of instruction-level parallelism and short dependency chains.  Or you could just do one fewer loop iteration and put a final set of `vfma` instructions + store after the loop, achieving software pipelining by peeling the load + shuffles from the first iter and peeling the FMAs + store from the last iter.

Comment: I guess the CPU already did a good gob on its own unrolling the loop since it only consists of 13 instructions of which 2 are fusable. I will try now try to align the data to 64 bytes

Comment: @Loran: Unrolling with lots of registers is important for stuff like a dot product, sum of an array, or other reduction where there's a loop-carried (across iterations) dependency chain.  [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) / [Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095394).  But out-of-order is excellent for loops like yours, allowing simple asm to run fast.

Comment: @Loran: How big are your arrays?  Are you bottlenecked on L3 cache or DRAM bandwidth, or worse on page faults from touching the output for the first time?  ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)).  If so, that could explain why your asm isn't able to run the expected 1.75x faster than the compiler's auto-vectorized code.

Comment: According to the benchmark results the asm functions suffer significantly more from bottlenecks on the memory side but I don't understand how the order of the function call influence this. 

I've also noticed through previous benchmarks of these functions that the order of the function calls matters, but it's not obvious to me why it is so, since every function must always start accessing the memory block at the beginning and by the end of the loop the data at the start of the memory block will be out of the cache again, because the memory block is so big.

Comment: Thank you. I've read through the post you've linked https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987. In this benchmark 240000 vectors have processed which isn't a lot for rendering graphics. I've run another benchmark with 96 vectors where the asm function runs more than 3x faster and with 0% memory bottleneck.

Comment: @Loran: We'd expect a 1.76x speedup from your asm vs. LLVM with aligned data hot in L1d; I just made an edit with uiCA links.  240000 x `float4` is 3.66 MiB, so one copy fits in L3 cache, but two copies exceed your 6MiB L3, so separate destination has to pay for RFOs plus it falls off the cliff into DRAM bandwidth instead of L3.  (I assume you saw the part in my "idiomatic ..." benchmarking answer about page faults on the first access to a page making the first access a lot slower, separate from cache and TLB misses.)

Comment: I've tried to benchmark the functions separately, but the measured CPU time always varied too much to be reliable. What do you recommend to prevent this memory issue and to reliably measure computation time? You've mentioned in your that never-written-to memory could be problematic. In the case of different dest/source vector arrays it would be the case for the source vector array, but why does it then only affect the asm functions?

Comment: You could try with NT stores for problem sizes where the source + result don't fit in cache, but much better if you can cache-block your actual use-case to improve computational intensity (amount of stuff you do with data while it's hot in L1d or L2 cache, or even in registers.)

Comment: @Loran: Your C++ function should also be running slower the first time it writes a newly allocated output buffer, compared to subsequent runs.  Do a warm-up run (or a `memset` with some non-zero value to avoid optimization to `calloc`) then time a repeat loop that calls your function multiple times with the same inputs and outputs.  You might need `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize` or just `asm("" ::: "memory")` to force the compiler to redo the work every time.

Comment: I've removed the software pipelining instructions in the asm function (the instructions which fetch and reorder the data for the next iteration) and it results in 30% less performance. It seems like, in this case, it is beneficial to have this software pipelining.

Comment: Interesting.  Is that still with unaligned loads?  Or with cache misses?  A chain of 4 mul/FMAs is 16 cycles of latency, and at about 2.5 uops per clock (including load/store and loop overhead) OoO exec has to be seeing about 40 uops ahead to find all the ILP.  But with load-use latency of maybe 7 cycles, `(16+7) * 2.5` is 57.5 uops ahead, and that's for an L1d cache hit.  So with split loads or cache misses increasing load latency more, we could be running into scheduler size limits.  (ROB = Reorder buffer capacity is huge, 352 uops on ICL/TGL). TGL scheduler size is supposed to be 160 entry

Comment: With an input of 2400 vectors the speed of both functions with and without the same source and dst array is pretty much identical. With an input size of 2400000 vectors with the same dst and source the speed is also identical. But with an input size of 2400000 vectors and different source and dst arrays the speed starts to vary more. The more often the functions are called the more the software pipelined function performs better but not always 30%. I've run multiple benchmarks and the highest performance difference was 50% with 10000 function calls in favor of the software pipelined version.

Comment: This would require more extensive testing than what I've done to come to a conclusion. The data is aligned to 64 or do you mean the load instructions? According to Agner Fog it doesn't make a difference in performance whether vmovups or vmovaps is used when the data is aligned. 

https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf

At page 125 under "Using unaligned read instructions"

Comment: @Loran: 2400 vectors x 16 bytes = 37.5 KiB which fits in L1d (just barely, so only one copy).  Same speed for that makes sense: OoO exec can hide latency.  And it fits in L2 so probably L1d prefetch is keeping load latency short, or L2 latency is not too bad.  The huge size, 2400000, is 36.6 MiB which doesn't fit in your 24 MiB L3 cache, so we're just limited by DRAM bandwidth and HW prefetch.  The middle size is 3.66 MiB which *does* fit in L3 but not L2.  Bandwidth is higher than DRAM, maybe high enough that SW pipelining is important to keep up with HW prefetch and generate new load addrs.

Comment: @Loran: With the data aligned by, there's no downside to `vmovups` loads.  If there's any no-RFO special-case for full-line stores, it might only apply with `vmovaps` stores, but more likely they'd just check the low bits of the address in the store-buffer entry since RFO is probably done on retirement or near the commit end of the store buffer.  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2020/05/18/icelake-zero-opt.html / [Why am I seeing more RFO (Read For Ownership) requests using REP MOVSB than with vmovdqa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66274948) - maybe only for storing zeros.

Comment: @Loran: But note that Ice Lake / Tiger Lake store-elimination was disabled in a 2021 microcode update (https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2021/06/17/rip-zero-opt.html) perhaps because of excessive paranoia about data-dependent performance revealing info about secret data. :(